# GEE code to compute mean annual NDVI time series

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth-engine, ndvi

I am new to GEE; I am trying to generate a time series NDVI for the July period (peak of summer) between 1984 to 2020. This typically includes harmonizing Landsat 5, 7, and 8. I used the code below and generated a time series, but the NDVI exported was black and showed no value in ArcGIS Pro. How can I improve the code?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0e5419ed54dcd04adf7e826d4f462e57

```
// / Load in Landsat 5, Landsat 7, Landsat 8, and the shapefile for the city of interest
// USER: Import your desired shapefile, then 1) uncomment the last line in this section and insert your asset path,
// eg: shape = ee.FeatureCollection("user/folder/shapefile"), 2) also comment out shape = austin;
var l5 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR")
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
var l7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR")
    var shape = table; // comment this out if you use the next line
    //shape = ee.FeatureCollection("users/Kolawole/Valley_Studyarea");

// Add the study area to the map
Map.addLayer(shape);

// Create date, bounds, and cloud cover filters-
var date_filter = ee.Filter.date('1984-01-01', '2020-01-01')
var bounds_filter = ee.Filter.calendarRange(7, 7, "month");
var date_bounds = ee.Filter.and(bounds_filter, date_filter);

// Create function which clips to extent of shapefile
var shape_clip = function (image){
  return image.clip(shape);
};

// Create function which masks cloudcover out of Landsat 8 OLI images
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

// Create a function which masks out cloud pixels from Landsat 5 and 7 imagery
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};

// Create mergeCollection function to merge together all available Landsat imagery (L5, L7, L8)
var mergeCollection = function() {
    // list the bands as described in the metadata for Landsat 5 and 7
    var l5names = ee.List(["B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7"]);
    var l7names = ee.List(["B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7"]);
     
    // list the common band names which will allow us to easily merge the bands and calculate NDVI
    var l5Bands = ee.List(['blue','green','red','nir','swir1','thermal1','swir2']);
    var l7Bands = ee.List(['blue','green','red','nir','swir1','thermal1', 'swir2']);
    
    // create NDVI function
    var makeNDVI = function(image){
      var NDVI = image.normalizedDifference(['nir', 'red']).rename('NDVI');
      return image.addBands(NDVI);
      };
      
    // create function to 'harmonize' Landsat 8 and other Landsat collections for more direct comparison of NDVI values
    var OLI2TM = function(oli){
      var slopes = ee.Image.constant([0.9785, 0.9542, 0.9825, 1.0073, 1.0171, 0.9949]);
      var itcp = ee.Image.constant([-0.0095, -0.0016, -0.0022, -0.0021, -0.0030, 0.0029]);
      var y = oli.select(['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7'], ['blue','green','red','nir','swir1','swir2']) // change l8 bands to common band names for use in NDVI calculation
        .subtract(itcp.multiply(10000)).divide(slopes)
        .set('system:time_start', oli.get('system:time_start'));
      return y.toShort();
    };
    
    // apply 'harmonizing' function and cloudmask function to Landsat 8 collection
    var l8_clean = l8.map(maskL8sr);
    var l8_corrected = l8_clean.map(OLI2TM);
    var l8images = l8_corrected.filter(date_bounds).map(makeNDVI); // apply filter to Landsat 8 collection and create an NDVI band
    
    // apply cloud mask to Landsat 5 collection
    var l5_clean = l5.map(cloudMaskL457);
    var l5_named = l5_clean.select(l5names, l5Bands); // rename bands for use in NDVI calculation
    var l5images = l5_named.filter(date_bounds).map(makeNDVI); // apply filter to Landsat 5 collection and create NDVI band
   
    // apply cloud mask to Landsat 7 collection
    var l7_clean = l7.map(cloudMaskL457);
    var l7_named = l7_clean.select(l7names, l7Bands); // rename bands for use in NDVI calculation
    var l7images = l7_named.filter(date_bounds).map(makeNDVI); // apply filter to Landsat 7 collection and create NDVI band

    // create image collection of all Landsat images  
    var myCollection = ee.ImageCollection(l5images.merge(l7images.merge(l8images)));
      return myCollection;
};


// // get a merged collection of all available Landsat surface reflectance tier 1 quality imagery, clip to shapefile extent
var LandsatCollection = mergeCollection().map(shape_clip);


// create a collection of NDVI maximum values per month per year
var months = ee.List.sequence(7, 7);
var years = ee.List.sequence(1984, 1989);
var byMonthYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function(y) {
    return months.map(function (m) {
      return LandsatCollection
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1984, 1999, 'year'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(7, 7, 'month'))
        .select('NDVI').mean()
        .set('month', m).set('year', y)
        .set('year', y);
  });
}).flatten());

print (byMonthYear, 'byMonthYear')
 
 
// // filter out images which do not contain any bands from collection
var nullimages = byMonthYear
    .map(function(image) {
      return image.set('count', image.bandNames().length());
    })
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('count', 1));

// apply reducer to get NDVI mean for each month (ie establish an NDVI norm for each month)
var ndviNorm = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  months.map(function(m) {
    return nullimages.filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', m))
    .mean()
    .set('month', m);
  })
);


  
  var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')
  
// Export the image, specifying the CRS, transform, and region.
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(byMonthYear, 'NDVI_Valley', 
                {name: "NDVI_data_{id}",
                region: table,
                scale: 30,  
                type: 'int8'})
                
                
  // Visualize the ndvi
                
var vis_params = {min:0, max:0.9, palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ]}

Map.addLayer(byMonthYear, vis_params, "NDVI")

    
var chart =  ui.Chart.image
      .series({
          imageCollection:byMonthYear ,
          region: table,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 500 
         })
          
print(chart)
```

Comment: Could you please add your code to the question body.

Comment: Thank you, Kadir.  The code has been added to the data.

Comment: The image likely just needs statistics constructed (which has nothing to do with GEE)

Comment: Thank you  @Vince, please how do I construct the statistics?

Comment: Lots of ways, but right-clicking is probably the easiest way to get there. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-statistics.htm